# Every Galois field $F$ of characteristic $p$ is perfect

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I'm trying to do **Exercise 2.6.13** from textbook *Groups, Matrices, and Vector Spaces - A Group Theoretic Approach to Linear Algebra* by James B. Carrell. Could you please confirm if my attempt is fine or contains logical mistakes?

> Every Galois field $F$ of characteristic $p$ is perfect, i.e. every element is a $p$th power.

**My attempt:**

We need a lemma from previous exercise

> Suppose $F$ is a field of characteristic $p$. If $a, b \in F$ and $a^{p}=b^{p}$, then $a=b$.

Consider a map $f: F \to F, x \mapsto x^p$. By our lemma, $f$ is injective. Moreover, $F$ is finite. Hence any $y \in F$ can be written as $y = x^p$ for some $p \in F$. This completes the proof.

Comment: @Mummytheturkey I have posted the proof of that lemma [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3739356/suppose-mathbbf-is-a-field-of-characteristic-p-show-that-if-a-b-in) in which I don't assume $F = \mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: @Mummytheturkey The implication $a^p=b^p\implies a=b$ is valid in any field of characteristic $p$.

Comment: Sorry this is my bad. I hastily confused the result with other results on the frobenius

Comment: Don't worry @Mummytheturkey. You're very welcome ^^

Comment: @LAD your proof looks good! Maybe it would be fun to prove why "every element is $p^{th}$ power" implies "irreducible polynomials have distinct roots" which is the usual definition of perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is @Mummy the turkey's comment that answers my question. I post it here to remove this question from unanswered list. All credits are given to @Mummy the turkey.

> Your proof looks good! Maybe it would be fun to prove why "every element is $p^{th}$ power" implies "irreducible polynomials have distinct roots" which is the usual definition of perfect.